# Angularjs npm start local server is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-start, angular-seed

I am newbie to angular js, i started creating a sample project like creating a basic template store using angular seed. Initially I faced some difficulties in installing bower components, but after some deep research in google, i would be 
able to find the solution. But now I am in a dilema. After installing bootstrap using bower command "bower install bootstrap" and I used boostrap started template. After that I was not able to start npm. when I tried to do "npm start" , 
I am getting the following error:

=======================================================================

```
$ npm start

> angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart C:\project\templatestore
> npm install


> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall C:\project\templatestore
> bower install

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

> angular-seed@0.0.0 start C:\project\templatestore
> http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1501:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Deepesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v8.9.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\project\templatestore\npm-debug.log
```

=======================================================================

I checked npm-debug.log and got the following error:

=============---------------------=====================----------------

```
$ cat npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: angular-seed@0.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: PATH: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\project\templatestore\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Ganesh\Scripts;C:\Ganesh;C:\Users\Deepesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
8 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: CWD: C:\project\templatestore
9 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm install' ]
10 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~prestart: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: angular-seed@0.0.0
12 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\project\templatestore\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Ganesh\Scripts;C:\Ganesh;C:\Users\Deepesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Deepesh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
14 verbose lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\project\templatestore
15 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app' ]
16 silly lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
18 verbose stack Error: angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
19 verbose pkgid angular-seed@0.0.0
20 verbose cwd C:\project\templatestore
21 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
22 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
23 error node v8.9.3
24 error npm  v3.10.10
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`
26 error Exit status 1
27 error Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app'.
27 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
27 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
27 error not with npm itself.
27 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
27 error     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app
27 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
27 error     npm bugs angular-seed
27 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
27 error     npm owner ls angular-seed
27 error There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

=============---------------------=====================----------------

package.json File:

=======================

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.7.7",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",

    "update-deps": "npm update",
    "postupdate-deps": "bower update",

    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",

    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",

    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",

    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",

    "update-index-async": "node -e \"var fs=require('fs'),indexFile='app/index-async.html',loaderFile='app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js',loaderText=fs.readFileSync(loaderFile,'utf-8').split(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/).join('sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map'),indexText=fs.readFileSync(indexFile,'utf-8').split(/\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/).join('//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n'+loaderText+'    //@@NG_LOADER_END@@');fs.writeFileSync(indexFile,indexText);\""
  }
}
```

=======================

index.html File:

=====================================

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="templateStore">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Template Store</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/templates">Template Store</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

      <div ng-view></div>

    </main><!-- /.container -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
    <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
    <script src="templates/templates.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

=====================================

Also no error is showing in console.
Maybe someone could help solve the problem :) ?

Comment: have you tried npm clean cache then npm install then run the server

Comment: You are more than welcome. am gonna post as answers if anyone else faced the same problem maybe this would help it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000

Your nodeJs might be already running or using this port. So open task manager and kill all nodeJs process(node.exe)

And then try nom start

Comment: Hello @Munna I have tried, but i didn't see any process running (node.exe) in Task Manager. I have even closed the Git Bash UI in WIndows. and tried npm start, but still showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this also might help try 
`npm clean cache` then `npm install` then run the server again